# I have bitcoin core wallet with missing btc

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have a bitcoin core wallet with out me sending transactions it sent out several times sent to the same address ..will it come back in my wallet

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the transaction ID, try entering it into a block explorer and checking they really were moved. If they were, then no, it's unlikely you can get the coins back, your computer may have been compromised

Comment: It's saying it's going in one large account and it was sending small amounts back but stop 3 days ago...I'm still missing 90%

Comment: If you don't own that address and don't know who owns it, chances are you will never get the coins back, as I said. Perhaps they have been stolen, sorry :(

Comment: are transaction address link to IP address

Comment: @JoshuaNa no, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41086/how-to-identify-the-owner-of-a-bitcoin-address, and please don't ask new questions in the comments section here